# Counting number of unique items from a dictionary

Tags: python

My program reads in a large log file. It then searches the file for the IP and TIME(whatever is in the brackets).

5.63.145.71 - - [30/Jun/2013:08:04:46 -0500] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "checks.panopta.com"
5.63.145.71 - - [30/Jun/2013:08:04:49 -0500] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "checks.panopta.com"
5.63.145.71 - - [30/Jun/2013:08:04:51 -0500] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "checks.panopta.com"

I want to read the whole file, and summarize the entries as follows:

Num 3 IP 5.63.145.1 TIME [30/Jun/2013:08:04:46 -0500]  Number of entries, IP, TIME and DATE

What I have so far:

```
import re


x = open("logssss.txt")

dic={}


for line in x:
    m = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line).group().split()
    c = re.search(r"\[(.+)\]",line).group().split()
    for i in range(len(m)):
        try:
            dic[m[i]] += 1 
        except:
            dic[m[i]] = 1
        k = dic.keys()
for i in range(len(k)):
    print dic[k[i]], k[i]
```

The above code displays correctly now! Thanks.

6 199.21.99.83

1 5.63.145.71

EDIT: So how about adding c into my output now, the timestamps are going to differ obviously, but just getting one of the values, on the same line, is that possible?

Comment: move your print loop outside your count loop

Comment: a defaultdict wouldn't need try ... except, and a Counter would be even more appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your print statement outside of the main loop

```
import re
x = open("logssss.txt")

dic={}


for line in x:
    m = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line).group().split()
    c = re.search(r"\[(.+)\]",line).group().split()
    for i in range(len(m)):
        try:
            dic[m[i]] += 1 
        except:
            dic[m[i]] = 1

for k,v in dic.iteritems(): #or items if Python 3.X
    print k, v
```

As a tip you could take advantage of pythons `Counter` class to replace your try except block

```
from collections import Counter
dic = Counter()
for line in x:
    m = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line).group().split()
    c = re.search(r"\[(.+)\]",line).group().split()
    for i in range(len(m)):
        dic[m[i]] += 1

for k,v in dic.iteritems(): #or items if Python 3.X
    print k, v
```

From your comment, I would just use a dictionary of lists, the count for each ip address could be extracted from the length of the list:

```
dic = {}
for line in x:
    m = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line).group().split()
    c = re.search(r"\[(.+)\]",line).group().split()
    for i in range(len(m)):
        dic.setdefault(m[i], []).append(c)

for k,v in dic.iteritems(): #or items if Python 3.X
    print k, len(v), v
```

Comment: Wow, interesting I didn't know that. Now say I want to include c now in my output....obviously these will have different time stamps for every entry, so I can't really summarize those, how would I include c on the same line along with k and v?

Comment: @user2592473: I edited my answer with an example of how you could do this

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Counter` which is much more efficient:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
for line in x:
    m = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line).group().split()
    cnt.update(m)
```

Then the printing done outside the main loop :

```
for k,v in cnt.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

to include c, a `defaultdict` would be more appropriate:

```
dict = defaultdict(list)
for line in x:
    m = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line).group().split()[0]
    c = re.search(r"\[(.+)\]",line).group().split()[0]
    dict[m].append(c)

for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    print k, len(v), v
```

It is my understanding that there is only 1 ip and date per line, hence the `[0]` to take the first and only occurence.

Comment: 199.21.99.83 - - [30/Jun/2013:07:19:45 -0500] 
199.21.99.83 - - [30/Jun/2013:07:19:49 -0500]   Is there a way to include c now as well in my output, the timestamps are different, so there is no way to really summzarize them, but an easy way to print on the same line as my previous output?

Comment: In a dict you could use the ip as the key, the date as the values and count the values

Comment: You sir, are amazing. Last thing, I am going to write another regex for what they did which is the "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "checks.panopta.com"   Could I append that onto dict[m] and still print that out, or does a dictionary not support 3 items?